# SharePoint 2013: Redirect to different page after cancel button is hit

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I am using SharePoint 2013. I have a custom list form for Feedback and Suggestions. Currently, to access the form, a user clicks on a link that takes them directly to the New Item form.

What I am trying to accomplish:
  - When a user clicks save, they are taken to a "Thank You" page.
  - When a user clicks cancel, they are taken back to the home page.

Things I have done:
  - On the link to the new form, I have added "?source=(URL for Thank You  Page"  - This accomplished the Save button task, but not the Cancel button task.

What I need help with:
  I need to know how to override the default cancel button. Right now it also redirects to the Thank you page. I need it to go to the Home Page.

The only thing I can do to edit the form is add code snippets.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include the HTML markup for the cancel button.

Comment: Part one: <input name="ctl00$ctl31$g_528cf443_45bd_472c_80e7_9649548c1e91$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl01$ctl00$diidIOGoBack" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" id="ctl00_ctl31_g_528cf443_45bd_472c_80e7_9649548c1e91_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl01_ctl00_diidIOGoBack" accesskey="C" onclick="STSNavigate('https://thankyou.aspx');return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions

Comment: Part Two: (&quot;ctl00$ctl31$g_528cf443_45bd_472c_80e7_9649548c1e91$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl01$ctl00$diidIOGoBack&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))" type="button" value="Cancel" target="_self">

Comment: It would not let me do it all in one comment

Comment: You can edit your original question and add in the code, and use the code formatting tool to format it.

Answer (score 0):

**SharePoint out of the box behavior is to send the user to the url in the Source querystring parameter WHEN THEY CLICK EITHER THE SAVE BUTTON OR THE CANCEL BUTTON on the new form.**

Since the OP is experiencing different behavior, it is possible (maybe even likely) that someone has added code to the master page of her site to override the oob behavior.

Anyone coming here looking for how to redirect the Cancel button, PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE check the behavior in your own site before spending hours hunting for some esoteric solution like one of my user's did. I showed him how to  use the source parameter, and we solved his issue in <1 minute.

Answer (score -1):

To accomplish this I did the following:

To redirect after Save button is pushed:

1. Create a Thank You page and copy the URL. Save for Later.
2. Add "?source=" then the url from step 1 to the end of the link that takes you to your new item page.
   EX: https://NewItemForm.aspx?Source=https://ThankYou.aspx

That will redirect to the Thank you page, if you hit save or cancel.

To Fix the Cancel button, do the following as well:

1. Go to your list > Form Web Parts (in the ribbon) > Default New Form
2. Insert Script Editor Web Part
3. Add the following code:

```js
<script>

function goToByePage(){
     window.location.assign("https://SitePages/Home.aspx");
}

function overrideCancel()
{
 //Custom input button
 var input = document.createElement('input');
 input.type = "button";
 input.name = "Cancel";
 input.value = "Cancel";
 input.id = "custominput";
 document.querySelectorAll('.ms-toolbar input[value=Cancel]')[1].parentNode.appendChild(input);
 document.getElementById("custominput").setAttribute("class", "ms-ButtonHeightWidth");
 
 //Hiding already implemented cancel buttons
 document.querySelectorAll('.ms-toolbar input[value=Cancel]')[0].style.display = "none";
 document.querySelectorAll('.ms-toolbar input[value=Cancel]')[1].style.display = "none";
 
 //this is main logic to move history back
 document.getElementById("custominput").setAttribute("onclick", "goToByePage();");
}



_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('overrideCancel');
</script>

<style>
#Ribbon\.ListForm\.Edit\.Commit\.Cancel-Large
{
 display:none;
}
</style>
```

This will remove the upper cancel button that was in the ribbon, and make the cancel button on the form take you back to whatever page is listed in the goToByePage function.

The code for this comes from 2 different sources:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190776/basic-custom-list-how-to-redirect-to-different-page-on-cancel-and-on-save-butto

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5036ab40-2d9b-4fe5-87a2-5805268eea07/how-to-override-behavior-of-the-cancel-button-in-the-ribbon-and-the-form?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Hope this helps someone else in the future!